# How to stream a HTML5 video from FTP without showing credentials?

Tags: php, html, video, ftp

I'm currently redesigning a small video portal. The videos are on a remote FTP. We planned to use a HTML5 video player (video.js). If we want to access this video via HTML, it would be:

```
<video><source src="ftp://user:pass@host.com/path/to/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Now everyone who looks at the source code could see the FTP credentials. What is the best way to prevent this? We already tried to pass the video over an own link (basically `file_get_contents`) but that's way too slow. And `mod_xsendfile` can't work with remote sources. Is there a way with good performance?

Comment: Why not use a proper media server? something like icecast?